# Program to print size of strings above threshold

Tags: python, python-3.x

python program which will take 2 arguments: a list of strings, and then a length threshold. The function should return a list of integers corresponding to the string lengths which are strictly greater than the given threshold.
For instance, if the arguments are the list:
[‘a’, ‘bb’, ‘c’, ‘abcde’]
And the threshold 1
The return value should be the list:
[2, 5]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

```
def program(li,thresh):
greater=[]
for i in li:
    if len(i)>thresh:
        greater.append(len(i))
return greater
```

This would be the simplest function that would return you your desired list.
You can take the input from user if you want something like this-

```
l=list(input().split())
t=int(input())
print(program(l,t))
```

For example the input is

```
a aa bhj v
1
```

The output will be

```
[2,3]
```

Comment: Or: `[len(value) for value in data if len(value) > threshold]`

Comment: @PrateekSurana, you're a very daring person. Answered a question with 6 downvotes!